# Android Wear - How to set divider space for WearableListView

Tags: android, android-listview, wear-os

I have a `WearableListView` on my wear app to display list items. I am able to display all the items . But i don't see any space between the items. How do i show some `empty space`(divider space) between items.

Comment: see RecyclerView.ItemDecoration class

Answer (score 0):

I have been working for almost one hour before I figured out :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32991449/2960083

The problem is that WearableListView is specifically made to show 3 items at the time